# Create an object collection based on another collection with different type

Tags: c#, linq, list, loops, collections

is it possible to simplify these statements?

```
List<YY> gss = new List<YY>();
foreach (var s in AA)
{
    gss.Add(new YY()
    {
         Color = s.Color,
         Offset = s.Offset
    });
}
SomeClass.ListYY = gss;
```

I believe its possible with LINQ, but i just dont know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SomeClass.ListYY = AA
    .Select(s => new YY() { Color = s.Color, Offset = s.Offset }).ToList();
```

For each s in AA, selecy a new YY and populate Offset and Color from s - then convert the result into a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeClass.ListYY = AA.Select(x => new YY { Color = x.Color, Offset = x.Offset }).ToList();
```